# lampp and php versions problems

Tags: php, sql

i have this error, i installed lampp 6 months ago and started a project, however, when i sent it to my laptop, the page its not working anymore because of dereference issues, this is the line causing the error

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SOME QUERY"))[0];
```

now, I've seen that my php version is 5.3.6 and i updated it to 5.5.5, and is giving me the same error... How do I get to install or upgrade lampp's version of php... thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_* was deleted from version 5.5. Use mysqli_ function or PDO class.

Prof: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Hey! I just tried also php 5.4, but it didn't worked (before php 5.5), i really think that is some lampp vs php error... (i think) Lampp is not using the PHP version that my laptop uses... it is using other one, i think that is happening.

Comment: Maybe not installed extention for work with mysql from php. php5-mysql package if you in Ubuntu